# SQL Inner join and duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

When I'm running my SQL query I got unwanted duplicates. In my query I will list (5) latest products added as the example below.

A product can have assigned multiple categories like this example:

```
- Product A, Category "men > clothes > pants"
- Product A, Category "women > clothes > pants"
- Product B, Category "men > clothes > shirts"
- Product B, Category "women > clothes > shirts"
```

Running my SQL query will give me the output:

```
- Product A
- Product A
- Product B
- Product B
```

What I want is just:

```
- Product A (Category "men > clothes > pants")
- Product B (Category "men > clothes > shirts")
```

**Product table**
ProductID 
ProductName

**Category join table**
JoinID
ProductID
Category3ID
**Category3 table**
Category3ID
Category2ID
Cat3Name
**Category2 table**
Category2ID
Category1ID
Cat2Name

**Category1 table**
Category1ID
Cat1Name

```
SELECT TOP 5 * FROM Product P
INNER JOIN Product_Category_Join PCJ ON (P.ProductID = PCJ.ProductID)
INNER JOIN Category3 C3 ON (PCJ.Category3ID = C3.Category3ID)
INNER JOIN Category2 C2 ON (C3.Category2ID = C2.Category2ID)
INNER JOIN Category1 C1 ON (C2.Category1ID = C1.Category1ID)
ORDER BY P.Date DESC
```

Comment: what does unwanted duplicates mean? You should show the output you get currently.

Comment: What is the rule? Do you always want to remove women? Or are you only interested in distinct product-names, so a single column? Your query using `*` suggests something different.

Comment: You could try adding the distinct keyword ...

Comment: I would use a CTE if possible for this.

Comment: Your query orders by `P.Date DESC` but your table doesn't contain this column.

Comment: Your query looks correct.  The cause of the duplicates would seem to be the underlying data.

Comment: Product A and Product A is exactly the same product and i only need to show one of them regardless if the category is "men" or "women".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to remove duplicates is to use a `CTE`(common-table-expression) and the `ROW_NUMBER` function. It has the advantage that you can select all columns if you want:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY P.ProductID ORDER BY P.Date DESC)
    FROM Product P
    INNER JOIN Product_Category_Join PCJ ON (P.ProductID = PCJ.ProductID)
    INNER JOIN Category3 C3 ON (PCJ.Category3ID = C3.Category3ID)
    INNER JOIN Category2 C2 ON (C3.Category2ID = C2.Category2ID)
    INNER JOIN Category1 C1 ON (C2.Category1ID = C1.Category1ID)
)
SELECT TOP 5 * 
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
ORDER BY Date DESC
```

Comment: Thanks @Tim Schmelter. I recon it should be  `WITH CTE AS`?
I got the following error: "The column 'ProductID' was specified multiple times for 'CTE'."

Comment: @EspenS.: yes. And you should list all columns `SELECT P.Col1,C2.Col2,C2.Col3` instead of using `SELECT *`.

Comment: Your solution solved my query problem! Your CTE example provided me with new useful insight.